# C++ virtual method that takes STL-style iterators

Tags: c++, templates, stl, iterator, virtual

I want to have an interface ModelGenerator which has a method generate() that takes an iterable list of Evidence and creates a Model. Using the STL pseudo-duck-typing iterator idiom...

```
template<class Model>
class ModelGenerator {
  public:
    template<class Iterator>
    virtual bool generate(Iterator begin, Iterator end, Model& model) = 0;
};
```

But virtual functions can’t be templated. So I have to template the whole class:

```
template<class Model, class Iterator>
class ModelGenerator {
  public:
    virtual bool generate(Iterator begin, Iterator end, Model& model) = 0;
};
```

Ideally what I’d like to do is something like this...

```
template<class Model, class Evidence>
class ModelGenerator {
  public:
    virtual bool generate(iterator<Evidence>& begin,
                          iterator<Evidence>& end,
                          Model& model) = 0;
};
```

But there is no such interface that iterators inherit from. (The class std::iterator only contains a bunch of typedefs, no methods.)

The only way I can think of doing it is to give ModelGenerator a method addEvidence() which adds them one by one before calling generate(), but then I have to give the ModelGenerator state which is a bit of a pain.

How can I write a virtual method that takes any STL container?

Comment: You should think about factoring out all the iterator operations from the virtual function. The templated function might generate a `std::vector< Evidence * >` and pass that to the `virtual` function. The performance cost and programming effort of that sort of wrapper is likely to be less than `any_iterator`/`any_range`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You seem to need an `any_iterator`. That's an iterator that performs type erasure to insulate you from the actual iterator implementation.

Adobe has an implementation of `any_iterator`:
http://stlab.adobe.com/classadobe_1_1any__iterator.html

Boost has an implementation of `any_range`:
http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_49_0/libs/range/doc/html/range/reference/ranges/any_range.html

Comment: Thanks! Do you know if any_iterator be found in any major libraries?

Comment: Keep in mind that `any_iterator` implementations are slow, so only use them when you have to.

Comment: @funkybluecoffee: Not Boost, unfortunately. Adobe has one: http://stlab.adobe.com/classadobe_1_1any__iterator.html

Comment: There's `any_range` in Boost.Range.

Comment: @funkybluecoffee: [Boost offers an implementation.](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_49_0/libs/range/doc/html/range/reference/ranges/any_range.html)

Comment: I was unaware of Boost's `any_range`, and it certainly beats using two `any_iterators`!

Comment: cool! I will try `any_range`. @MooingDuck, what makes `any_iterator` slow?

Comment: @funkybluecoffee: Type erasure works with polymorphism and `virtual` methods, that's what makes it slow.

Comment: @K-ballo: Given that the whole point of the question is that he wants to make virtual function calls, I think we can assume that the virtual call overhead is unlikely to be relevant to his uses.

Comment: @abarnert: The thing with `any_iterator` is that each advance, comparison, increment operation involves a `virtual` call. So the overhead is quite considerable, enough to be worth mention.

Answer (score 0):

You could consider to use template specialisation instead of virtual methods to this end. From what I understand, you have a unique Evidence class, a number of distinct Model classes and whant to create a generic factory to produce a selected Model from a sequence of Evidences.

```
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>

struct Model1 { };
struct Model2 { };
struct Evidence { };

template<class Model>
struct ModelGenerator;

template<>
struct ModelGenerator<Model1>
{
    typedef Model1 model_type;

    template<class Iterator>
    model_type generate(Iterator begin, Iterator end)
    {
        std::cout << "Generate Model1\n";
        return model_type();
    }
};

template<>
struct ModelGenerator<Model2>
{
    typedef Model2 model_type;

    template<class Iterator>
    model_type generate(Iterator begin, Iterator end)
    {
        std::cout << "Generate Model2\n";
        return model_type();
    }
};

template<class Model, class Iterator>
Model make_model(Iterator begin, Iterator end)
{
    ModelGenerator<Model> gen;
    return gen.generate(begin, end);
}
```

You can use it this way:

```
int main()
{
    std::vector<Evidence> v;

    Model1 m1 = make_model<Model1>(v.begin(), v.end());
    Model2 m2 = make_model<Model2>(v.begin(), v.end());
}
```